How can I get nftables to log the data transferred per session?
With a standard log rule "ct state new" we get the details about a new session, however, we only get the data size of the first packet looking in LEN i.e.
2024-06-15T10:11:31.829667+00:00 deepu kernel: ALLOW INPUT: IN=ens33 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:3a:f9:d3:87:89:65:08:cc SRC=172.16.0.1 DST=172.16.0.255 LEN=72 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=64 ID=32643 PROTO=UDP SPT=57621 DPT=57621
In this, we see 72 bytes.
How can we log the total volume of data transferred in that session?  For example, if this was a 100MB file download, I'd want to see 100MB download, plus the few small packets of TCP establishment etc.

The basic iptables/nftables counters only track the number of bytes/packages that have matched a particular rule, regardless of which connection they belong to.
For per-session statistics, you would need to track individual connections and log connection statistics whenever a connection ends. Sounds like a job for the connection tracking subsystem!
At least on Debian, there is a conntrackd package, which includes a configuration example at /usr/share/doc/conntrackd/examples/stats/conntrackd.conf, for writing statistics about ending connections to /var/log/conntrackd-stats.log by default. This might be just about exactly what you're asking for.

Many, many thanks.  I've managed to "tail" this log file add both send_bytes and return_bytes to create total_bytes.
This is perfect - thanks!
